# How can I get multiple arrays into UIPickerview

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have an problem in `UIPickerview`, it is displayed in this screenshot.

[Screenshot of my UIPickerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOjR3.png)

I have three arrays. Each array is passed into `UIPickerview`. I can display the three columns in `UIPickerview`.

My problem is that the arrays are not passed into each column and are not passed into the sub-columns.

How can I solve the problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In UIPickerView delegate:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent (NSInteger)component

check for

if(component == 0)

{

   //use Array1

}

else if(component == 1)

{

   //use Array2

}

else if(component == 2)
{

   //use Array3

}
```